# How do I require Stylus in Spine using CommonJS?

Tags: javascript, spine.js, commonjs, stylus

I would like to use the [javascript API](http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/docs/js.html) Stylus offers  in my Spine app.

To do this, I have to require Stylus.

Because Stylus is a dependency of Hem I tried requiring it in the index.coffee:

```
Stylus    ?= require('stylus')
```

But this resulted in an error:

```
uncaught exception: module Stylus not found
```

Then I tried including Stylus independently in the package.json

```
{
  "name": "Blank",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
     "node": "0.6.x",
     "npm":  "1.0.x"
  },
  "dependencies": { 
    "serveup": "~0.0.2",
    "hem": "~0.1.7",
    "stylus" : "~0.22.6",
    "es5-shimify": "~0.0.1",
    "json2ify": "~0.0.1",
    "jqueryify": "~0.0.1",
    "spine": "~1.0.5",
    "spine.mobile": "~1.0.0",
    "gfx": "~0.0.4"
  }
}
```

And in my slug.json

```
{
  "dependencies": [
    "es5-shimify", 
    "json2ify", 
    "jqueryify", 
    "spine",
    "spine/lib/local",
    "spine/lib/ajax",
    "spine/lib/relation",
    "spine/lib/route",
    "spine/lib/tmpl",
    "spine/lib/manager",
    "stylus"
  ],
  "libs": []
}
```

But this resulted in an error in the server log:

```
Unhandled error!
```

How can I require Stylus and make use of its API in Spine?

Comment: When do you get the error exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you forgot to run `npm install` after adding the stylus dependency into your app package.json.

Comment: I ran npm install. I can also see a **stylus** folder in my **node_modules** folder. I think the problem could be that stylus is dependent on hem. I can also see a **stylus** folder inside the **node_modules** folder of **hem**. But I dont know how to require this in my slug.json.

Comment: I got the following output when I ran npm install:      `stylus@0.22.6 ./node_modules/stylus 
├── growl@1.1.0
├── mkdirp@0.0.7
└── cssom@0.2.1`